# Variable size inputs for CNTK in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, cntk

I want to feed a CNN with images from different resolutions using Keras. Thus, I defined the input layer shape as (None,None,3), since the images have 3 channels. My problem is that this works well on TensorFlow, but gives and error on CNTK (and I must use CNTK).

The following python code illustrates my problem:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input


input_layer = Input(shape=(None,None,3),name='input')

x = Conv2D(16,3)(input_layer)
x = Conv2D(16,3)(x)
model = Model(input=input_layer,output=x)
model.compile('adam','mse')

X = np.random.random((1,32,32,3))
Y = model.predict(X)
print Y.shape
```

If I run using Keras+TensorFlow it will execute nicely, however changing Keras backend to CNTK gives the error:

```
ValueError: Convolution operation requires that kernel dim 3 <= input dim 1.
```

As far as I could find over the internet, this problem should have been fixed from CNTK 2.2 and so on, however I'm using CNTK 2.5. Any ideas on how can I overcome this issue?